# Python, pandas histogram and Jensen Shannon Divergence

Tags: python, pandas, twitter, distribution

I have some data from Twitter, which looks like this:

> index, Time(second), Time(date), Hashtags, User ID
>
> 0 1.464898e+09 /  2016-06-02 22:00:00 / Brexit InOrOut/ 598724350

I made a code which, separates the data for hashtags, and made histogram by time.

My problem is that, I want to compare two hashtag distribution with Jensen Shannon Divergence, but the lenght of the histograms is unequal, and I work with Python Pandas.

I know how to implement the Jensen Shannon Divergence, so my problem is how to do this on a pandas data frame histogram, which is unequal.